# How to deploy the code on heroku from assembla

Tags: git, heroku, version-control, assembla

I want to deploy push code from assembla to heroku when some one has pushed the code on assembla then I want it should automatically deploy on heroku.

Please suggest me how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**disclaimer, I work for Assembla

The problem with deploying directly to Heroku from Assembla is that you will have to include your credentials, theoretically it is possible with a post-receive hook, but I would advise against this and Assembla would most likely reject the post-receive hook submission unless you know a way to work around the authentication problem.

However, you can accomplish this with the SSH tool, which will deploy from a server that you provide. So you would need to have a plan that includes the SSH tool, then a server that the SSH tool can connect to and run a script that pulls your repo and then pushes out to Heroku. You can put the SSH tool job to run "on commit" and it will automatically run this job for you.